# Rescaling a scaled value using bc command

Tags: bash, bc

I am trying to find square root of 12345 and then scale it to 100 decimal places using the command shown below:

```
val=$(bc <<< "scale=100 ; sqrt ( 12345) " )
```

But the problem is I want to rescale the value to 10 decimal places using bc only in echo command but it is not working, I tried following code of lines but none worked.

```
echo "scale=10 ; "$val" " | bc

echo "scale=10 ; $val " | bc

echo "scale=10 ; val " | bc
```

Can somebody here help me and make out the difference.

Note: I don't want to directly scale the value to 10 places in sqrt() because last place of decimal value differ from the answer so to have high accuracy I have to do in this way.

Comment: `bc` doesn't seem to be very useful for output formatting. As an illustration, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965411/bash-script-specify-bc-output-number-format. Use shell code or `awk` etc to scale the output to ten decimals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not worried about rounding in bc, you can do:

```
$ echo "scale=10 ; "$val/1" " | bc
111.1080555135
```

It is when a value gets divided (even by 1) that the number of decimals gets adjusted to the `scale`.

Of course, you can always use the shell printf (again, some rounding might crawl in).

```
$ printf '%5.10f\n' "$val"
111.1080555135
```

Why do you need precision?

Comment: Oh thnx btw printf "%.10f" $(bc -q <<< scale =10 \; $a ) actually worked for me as suugested by first comment in my question , I need precise value for some sharp manipulation.